# Template code blocks in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, block

Recently I was working on a project, which required a lot of constructs like "repeat" and "foreach". I know that there are no such constructs in C++, but I tried to imagine what they might look like.

```
repeat(count)
{
   ...
}

foreach(someList, it)
{
   ...
}
```

Since template inline functions are already supported in C++, very little change is required to support template code blocks also. One of possible syntax could be like this:

```
template<unsigned count> repeat(unsigned count)
while(count--) __code;

template <class ContainerT, typename ContainerT::iterator it>
foreach(ContainerT& cn, typename ContainerT::iterator it)
    for(typename ContainerT::iterator it=cn.begin(); it!=cn.end(); ++it) __code;
```

What do you think about this syntax? Is there any chance for such feature to be added in future C++ versions? Do you know any workarounds to implement something like this in the current C++ version?

Comment: There is a [range-base `for` loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Range-based_for_loop) in C++11.

Comment: And with C++11 [function object wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Polymorphic_wrappers_for_function_objects) and [lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) these two function are very easy to implement.

Comment: By the way, C++ have had [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) for many years.

Comment: These are just two examples. I do not mean that I absolutely need repeat and foreach. I wonder why there is no such thing as template code blocks, which could move C++ to a new level. From implementation standpoint, there is little difference for the compiler between inline template functions and template code blocks.

Comment: No, the standard library solves this by using templated "predicate" objects. See for example the `std::for_each` reference linked in my previous comment. Or my answer of course. :)

Comment: Compare this: std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int &n){ n++; }); and this: foreach(nums, it) { ++*it; }

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any chance for such feature to be added in future C++ versions?

C++11 has range-based `for` loops:

```
for (auto elem : cont) // (perhaps use auto&, auto const&, or auto&&,
                       //  depending on your use case)
{
    // Do what you want with elem...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::for_each()` with a lambda:

```
std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), 
    [&] (decltype(cont)::value_type const& elem)
//                                  ^^^^^^
//                                  Or whatever fits your needs
{
    // Do what you want with elem...
}
```

Also, [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) has versions of the C++ Standard algorithms that allow working on ranges rather than on pairs of iterators:

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

// ...

std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
boost::for_each(v, [] (int i) { std::cout << i * 2 << std::endl; });
```

Comment: I never use boost in my projects, but thanks for the hints. I still hope to receive answers with a wider perspective on the problem. This is not a question about repeat/foreach in particular. It is a question about template blocks of code in general.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a proper body for the loops, look at how the C++ standard library does it: It uses "predicates" as arguments to similar functions, and these can be any callable object (function pointers, static member function pointers, [functor objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B), and (since C++11) [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects, [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) expressions or [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)).

So your `repeat` function could be something like this:

```
template<typename Tpred>
void repeat(unsigned count, Tpred predicate)
{
    while (count--)
        predicate();
}
```

---

The above function could be used as

```
repeat(10, [](){ std::cout << "hello\n"; });
```

The call above would cause the lambda to be called  ten times, so it would print `"hello"` ten times.

Comment: So what would the code that uses this repeat definition look like? Assuming we are using C++11?

Comment: @bkxp Added simple example. If you want to pass more arguments to the lambda, then you could use `std::bind` to pass arbitrary arguments.

Comment: Seriously, [](){ ? Compare it with how it would look like with codeblock templates:  repeat(10) { std::cout << "hello\m"; }

Comment: @bkxp That's how C++ is specified. There is simply no way of doing what you want, unless you want to write your own compiler and add things like that as an extension. But then it's no longer C++ but a completely new language _based_ on C++. You either have to live with what you have, and work withing those confines, or find (or make) something else that does what you want.

Comment: By your logic C++11 is no longer C++, too, because it introduces lambda-functions and other new stuff. But I assume this is not the latest version of the standard, and maybe in C++14 we will see more features. Can't we discuss probable features now? By the way in QT they had to introduce a preprocessor because some features were lacking. This is a kludge, of course, but with template code blocks they wouldn't have to do that. Writing a programming language from scratch is a more complex task than extending an existing language.